# Django filter case insensitive

Tags: django, filter, case-insensitive

I wrote this Django viewset that allows users to filter and query data

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from rest_framework import viewsets

from API.models import Record
from API.serializers import RecordSerializer


 class    CountViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """List of all traffic count Counts"""
queryset = Record.objects.all().select_related("count")
serializer_class = RecordSerializer
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filterset_fields = (
    "road",
    "date",
    "count_method",
    "count_method__basic_count_method",
    "count_method__detailed_count_method",
    "location",
    "road__direction",
    "road__category",
    "road__junc_start",
    "road__junc_end",
    "road__road__name",
    "date__year",
    "location__count_point_ref",
    "road__category__name",
    "road__junc_start__name",
    "road__junc_end__name",
    "road__direction__name",
)
```

And I would like to make it case insensitive and allow searches that contain partially a string so that user can query without knowing the correct “road name” for example:

curl -X GET /count/?road__category__name=TA" -H "accept: application/json

Answer (score 1):

You can try `road__category__name__icontains` if it doesn't work you have to declare it as a method filed in your Custom filter class,
`i` letter for Case-insensitive,
Documentaion refference :
[Django icontains Doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)